# Efficient Way to Query GA and Output Multiple Months to Google Sheet

Tags: google-analytics-api

I'm wondering if anyone could give me tips or example code on how to query and output multiple months worth of data to a Google Sheet. For example, I'd like to create a table that lists all of the eventLables and the totalEvents for each during the last 3 months.

```
For instance:
                May    June   July
Video Plays      5     10      20
External Links   6      8      15
Get Directions   6      2       3
```

Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: What languages are you using? what does the data you are importing from look like? Where is the data currently? (server, desktop, etc) What have you already tried?

Comment: Any reason why [Google Analytics Spreadsheet Add on](https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/google-analytics-spreadsheet-add-on) doesn't meet your needs? If you are willing to do a bit of coding the [Analytics Reporting API v4](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/) is part of the [Apps Script framework](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/).